# How to evaluate text of child element in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have identified parent elements and added them to the list 'targetTags'.  I am able to change the .css of a child element with the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < targetTags.length; i++) {                                  
    console.log($(targetTags[i]).children("div.amount").text);                               
     $(targetTags[i]).children("div.amount").css({ "color": "red" });
}
```

However, I only wish to change the .css of the child element if the inner text of the child element 'amount' is negative.  How do I grab that inner text so that I can evaluate it?  I tried the following if statement but it doesn't work.  It doesn't bring back the numerical value, just a big long object:

```
 if ($(targetTags[i]).children("div.amount").text < 0) { ... }
```

Comment: Try with `.text()` - but you'll also need to convert to a number if you're doing numerical comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

text is method. So use text()

```
if ($(targetTags[i]).children("div.amount").text() < 0) { ... }
```